# emergency stop when macro biblatex and standalone are used

Tags: biblatex, biber, standalone

I want to use a personal macro for citing with biblatex that comes from this [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470884/use-all-name-initials-when-using-biblatex-mcite-command). But I have two issues with it.

1. When I do not use the personal macro `\defbibentrysetlabel`, I get from biber  the error `ERROR - Data file 'test-msets.bib' cannot be read in encoding 'utf8'`. I think that is linked to the fact that the file is empty.
2. When I use this command in an embedded file with `standalone`, I get the error `! Emergency stop.`, that I do not know how to solve.

Here is an example, made of 3 files:

The first file is the common preamble named `preamble.tex`

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,
  mcite=true,
  subentry,
  maxcitenames=3,
  backend=biber
  ]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
    % warning the file called \blxmset@bibfile@name will be
    % overwritten without warning
    \def\blxmset@bibfile@name{\jobname -msets.bib}
    \newwrite\blxmset@bibfile
    \immediate\openout\blxmset@bibfile=\blxmset@bibfile@name

    \AtEndDocument{%
      \closeout\blxmset@bibfile}

    \newrobustcmd*{\defbibentrysetlabel}[3]{%
      \@bsphack
      \begingroup
      \immediate\write\blxmset@bibfile{%
        @set{#1, entryset = {\unexpanded{#3}}, %
              shorthand = {\unexpanded{#2}},}%
      }%
      \nocite{#1}%
      \@esphack}

    \addbibresource{\blxmset@bibfile@name}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Yvon_1935,
  title     = {La Th\'eorie Statistique Des Fluides et l'\'equation d'\'etat},
  series    = {Actualit\'es Scientifiques et Industrielles ; {Th\'eories} M\'ecaniques (Hydrodynamique-Acoustique)},
  publisher = {Hermann \& cie},
  date      = {1935},
  author    = {Yvon, Jacques},
  lccn      = {37018772}
}
@article{Born_1946,
  title        = {A General Kinetic Theory of Liquids {I}. {The} Molecular Distribution Functions},
  volume       = {188},
  issn         = {2053-9169},
  doi          = {10.1098/rspa.1946.0093},
  number       = {1012},
  journaltitle = {Proceedings of the Royal Society of London. Series A. Mathematical and Physical Sciences},
  date         = {1946-12-31},
  pages        = {10-18},
  author       = {Born, Max and Green, Herbert Sydney},
}
@article{Kirkwood_1946,
  title        = {The Statistical Mechanical Theory of Transport Processes {I}. {General} Theory},
  volume       = {14},
  url          = {http://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1724117},
  doi          = {10.1063/1.1724117},
  number       = {3},
  journaltitle = {The Journal of Chemical Physics},
  urldate      = {2019-01-16},
  date         = {1946-03},
  pages        = {180-201},
  author       = {Kirkwood, John Gamble},
}
@article{Bogolioubov_1945,
  title        = {Kinetic Equations},
  volume       = {10},
  number       = {3},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Physics USSR},
  date         = {1945},
  pages        = {265-274},
  author       = {Bogolioubov, Nikola\"i Nikola\"ievitch}
}
@article{Boncella_1984,
  author  = {Boncella, James M. and Andersen, Richard A.},
  journal = {Inorg. Chem.},
  pages   = {432--437},
  volume  = {23},
  year    = {1984},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{\jobname.bib}
```

Then the embedded file `test_include.tex` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{preamble.tex}

\begin{document}
    A first citation~\cite{Boncella_1984}.
    And another that I want to cite as a set BBGKY45 \defbibentrysetlabel{setBBGKY}{BBGKY45}{Yvon_1935,Bogolioubov_1945,Born_1946,Kirkwood_1946}\cite{setBBGKY}.

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the main `test_main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{preamble.tex}

\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
    test3 \cite{Boncella_1984}

    \input{./test_include.tex}
\end{document}
```

In this example I can compile `test_include.tex` without any problem.
But when I try to compile `test_main.tex` as it I get the 2nd problem at first compilation. And if I comment the line `\input{./test_include.tex}`, I get the 1st problem at biber compilation.

Comment: `standalone` is a tricky beast, in particular when used with `biblatex`, see for example also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267727/35864

Comment: the option `group=false` from the `standalone` package seems to solve the 2nd problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of my answer to [Use all name initials when using biblatex mcite command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470884/35864) contained a bug.

The definition of `\defbibentrysetlabel` contained a `\begingroup` but no matching `\endgroup`. The `\begingroup` can be dropped. The definition should read

```
\newrobustcmd*{\defbibentrysetlabel}[3]{%
  \@bsphack
  \immediate\write\blxmset@bibfile{%
    @set{#1, entryset = {\unexpanded{#3}}, %
          shorthand = {\unexpanded{#2}},}%
  }%
  \nocite{#1}%
  \@esphack}
```

Furthermore Biber does not like empty `.bib` files without entries and so like the `-blx.bib` entry we can simply add a fake `@comment` entry with

```
\immediate\write\blxmset@bibfile{%
  @comment{auxiliary file for \string\defbibentrysetlabel}^^J%
  @comment{This file may safely be deleted.
    It will be recreated as required.}}
```

The complete implementation in `\makeatletter...\makeatother` should therefore be

```
\makeatletter
% warning the file called \blxmset@bibfile@name will be
% overwritten without warning
\def\blxmset@bibfile@name{\jobname -msets.bib}
\newwrite\blxmset@bibfile
\immediate\openout\blxmset@bibfile=\blxmset@bibfile@name
\immediate\write\blxmset@bibfile{%
  @comment{auxiliary file for \string\defbibentrysetlabel}^^J%
  @comment{This file may safely be deleted.
    It will be recreated as required.}}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeout\blxmset@bibfile}

\newrobustcmd*{\defbibentrysetlabel}[3]{%
  \@bsphack
  \immediate\write\blxmset@bibfile{%
    @set{#1, entryset = {\unexpanded{#3}}, %
          shorthand = {\unexpanded{#2}},}%
  }%
  \nocite{#1}%
  \@esphack}

\addbibresource{\blxmset@bibfile@name}
\makeatother
```

I have edited the other answer accordingly.